# How do I read Element in specific XML file in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

my file XML:

```
<document xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" version="1.0" producer="ABBYY FineReader Engine 11" languages="" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml">
 <page width="1006" height="636" resolution="300" originalCoords="1" rotation="RotatedUpsidedown">


<block blockType="Text" blockName="" l="979" t="613" r="1006" b="636"><region><rect l="979" t="613" r="1006" b="636"/></region>
<text>
<par lineSpacing="890">
<line baseline="17" l="985" t="620" r="1006" b="636"><formatting lang="EnglishUnitedStates"><charParams l="985" t="620" r="1006" b="636" suspicious="1">r</charParams></formatting></line></par>
</text>
</block>


<block blockType="Barcode" blockName="" l="242" t="21" r="772" b="116"><region><rect l="242" t="21" r="772" b="116"/></region>
<text>
<par><line baseline="0" l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"><formatting lang="">049102580225180310</formatting></line></par>
</text>
<barcodeInfo type="INTERLEAVED25"/>
</block>

</page>
</document>
```

I want extract number 049102580225180310 located in `<formatting>..</formatting>`

I try this code:

```
XElement racine = XElement.Load("test_XML.xml");

var query = from xx in racine.Elements(XName.Get("block"))
            select new
            {
                CodeBar= xx.Attribute(XName.Get("formatting")).Value
            };
```

But I haven't nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a console program, that gets the 2nd formatting (where lang='') node.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load("c:\\temp\\test.xml");

            NameTable nt = new NameTable();
            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr;
            nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("html", xml.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

            XmlNode ndFormat = xml.SelectSingleNode("//html:formatting[@lang='']", nsmgr);
            if (ndFormat != null) {
                Console.WriteLine(ndFormat.InnerText);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple issues here:

- Your XML has a default namespace in the root node:

  ```
  <document xmlns="http://www.abbyy.com/FineReader_xml/FineReader10-schema-v1.xml" version="1.0"
  ```

  Thus all child elements are in this namespace, and so when querying for elements by their [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name(v=vs.110).aspx) the appropriate namespace must be used when constructing an `XName` for which to search.
- The `<formatting>` nodes are not direct children of the `<block>` nodes, they are nested within several levels of XML.  Also, they are XML elements, not XML attributes.

  Similarly the `<block>` elements are not direct children of the `<document>` root element, they are nested inside a `<page>` element.

  In such cases [`XElement.Descendants(name)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) can be used to find nested elements by name.

Thus your query should be:

```
var ns = racine.Name.Namespace; // The root default namespace used by all the elements in the XML.

var query = from block in racine.Descendants(ns + "block")
            from formatting in block.Descendants(ns + "formatting")
            select new
            {
                CodeBar= (string)formatting,
            };
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CEhH6W) that outputs the values of the two `<formatting>` elements:

```
{ CodeBar = r }
{ CodeBar = 049102580225180310 }
```